# Custom Output rails json api with :include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api-design

Right now I have my api rendering this json

```
[
       {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "1",
              "matches": [{
                            "score_a": 1,
                            "score_b": 3,
                            "time": "2016-05-20T15:00:00.000Z",
                             "teams": [
                                        {
                                          "name": "Team 1",
                                           "logo_url":"test.jpg"
                                          },
                                         {
                                           "name": "Team 2",
                                           "logo_url": "test.2jpg"
                                          }
                                        ]
                            }]

   }
]
```

I am rendering this using the render :json helper of Rails. Like this:

```
@calendar = Journey.all

render json: @calendar, include: { matches: 
                                     { include: { teams: { } }} 
                                  }
```

How ever, the front end developer (He is consuming the API through Angular)  is asking me the change the structure of the JSON, he needs the teams to be in the same level as the match. Some thing like this:

```
[
       {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "1",
              "matches": [{
                            "score_a": 1,
                            "score_b": 3,
                            "time": "2016-05-20T15:00:00.000Z",
                             "team_a_name": "Team 1",
                             "team_a_logo_url":"test.jpg",
                             "team_b_name": "Team 2",
                             "team_b_logo_url": "test.2jpg",

                            }]

   }
]
```

As you can see the the matches an the teams are now merged.

How can I achieve this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replaced `alphabets` with `digits`

```
  teams = [
            {
               "name": "Team 1",
               "logo_url":"test.jpg"
            },
            {
               "name": "Team 2",
               "logo_url": "test.2jpg"
            }
          ]
```

`teams` is your given hash

```
  array = []

  teams.count.times {|i| 
       teams[i].keys.each do |k,v|
          key = "team_"+ (i+1).to_s + "_"+k.to_s
          array.push(key)
       end
   }

  #=> ["team_1_name", "team_1_logo_url", "team_2_name", "team_2_logo_url"]
```

Now we will create array for your values

```
 value_array = []

 teams.each do |k|
    k.each do |key, val|
      value_array.push(val)
    end
 end

#=> ["Team 1", "test.jpg", "Team 2", "test.2jpg"]
```

Now we are going to combine both arrays

```
 new_teams = Hash[*array.zip(value_array).flatten]
 #=> {"team_1_name"=>"Team 1", "team_1_logo_url"=>"test.jpg", "team_2_name"=>"Team 2", "team_2_logo_url"=>"test.2jpg"}
```

now you can assign `new_teams` in your json

```
render json: @calendar, include: { matches: 
                                 { include: { teams: new_teams }} 
                              }
```